# Mathematical Logic Application of Inference Rule

Tags: discrete-mathematics

All men are mortal.

Socrates is a man.

Therefore Socrates is mortal

---

According to me, if we want to represent in mathematical logic, it will be like

All men are mortal-M

Socrates is a man-S

Therefore Socrates is mortal- $S\wedge M$

---

But they are using Modus Ponens .

modus ponens applicable, if the second sentence is "If Socrates is man, then he is mortal"

But here that sentence not present. Am I right?

Comment: No, unfortunately you're not right. I would read $S \land M$ as "Socrates is a man and all men are mortal". This is a stronger statement than saying "Socrates is mortal". For example, if Socrates was the name of my (mortal) cat, then "Socrates is mortal" would still be true, but "Socrates is a man and all men are mortal" would not be true. That is, the two statements are different.

Comment: But is modus ponens correct application for it?

Comment: NO; it is a [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism): it needs [(monadic) predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

Comment: Using only propositional calculus you cannot show that it is a valid argument.

Comment: I also take issue with the solution's interpretation. The statement "All men are mortal" is stronger than saying "If Socrates is a man, then Socrates is mortal". The latter is a statement purely about Socrates, but the former is a statement about all men. The statement all men are mortal could be interpreted as $\forall x, \operatorname{Man}(x) \implies \operatorname{Mortal}(x)$. The first step would be universal instantiation to substitute Socrates in for $x$, to say $\operatorname{Man}(\mathrm{Socrates}) \implies \operatorname{Mortal}(\mathrm{Socrates})$, then use modus ponens.

Answer (score 1):

For all x, (if x is a man, then x is mortal).
An instance of the above:
if Socrates is a man, then Socrates is mortal.
Socrates is a man.
Socrates is mortal.